# Coldfusion XMLParse with Hyphen

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing, coldfusion-9

I am trying to create a query from xml.  I am using xmlparse, but the main node has a hypen in it.  I am not sure how to build it so I can loop through the products.  Here is what it looks like

http://www.screencast.com/t/GhCgHTymMsR1

I have been trying to do this, but its not working or i am missing something.

```
<cfset result = xmlParse(result.Filecontent)>
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="#arrayLen(result["cj-api"]products.product)#">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cj-api>
  <products total-matched="363" records-returned="2" page-number="1">
    <product>
      <ad-id>10773572</ad-id>
      <advertiser-id>2955746</advertiser-id>
      <advertiser-name>Shopko</advertiser-name>
      <advertiser-category>picture books</advertiser-category>
      <buy-url>http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-5917360-10773572?url=http%3A%2F%2Fshopko.com%2Fdetail%2FLEGO-Batman%3A-The-Visual-Book%2F48364%2F0000&amp;cjsku=48364</buy-url>
  <catalog-id>cjo:398</catalog-id>
  <currency>USD</currency>
  <description>Enter the world of your favorite LEGO&amp;#174; super hero in the first ever guide to LEGO&amp;#174; Batman&amp;#8482;! LEGO Batman: The Visual Dictionary combines DK's famous Visual Dictionary format with the adventurous world of the LEGO Caped Crusader.Every set and minifigure from the LEGO Batman universe will now be at your fingertips.</description>
  <image-url>http://shopko.com/items/shopko/images/small/48364_0000.jpg</image-url>
  <in-stock></in-stock>
  <isbn></isbn>
  <manufacturer-name></manufacturer-name>
  <manufacturer-sku></manufacturer-sku>
  <name>LEGO Batman: The Visual Book</name>
  <price>21.99</price>
  <retail-price>21.99</retail-price>
  <sale-price>21.99</sale-price>
  <sku>48364</sku>
  <upc></upc>
</product>
<product>
  <ad-id>10773572</ad-id>
  <advertiser-id>2955746</advertiser-id>
  <advertiser-name>Shopko</advertiser-name>
  <advertiser-category>toy figures &amp; playsets</advertiser-category>
  <buy-url>http://www.jdoqocy.com/click-5917360-10773572?url=http%3A%2F%2Fshopko.com%2Fdetail%2FLEGO-Friends-Olivias-Speedboat%2F59022%2F0000&amp;cjsku=59022</buy-url>
  <catalog-id>cjo:398</catalog-id>
  <currency>USD</currency>
  <description>All aboard for fun in the sun with Olivia's Speedboat!Includes Olivia mini-doll figure Features sand castle, shovel, bucket, beach towel, umbrella and cupBring the LEGO&amp;#174; Friends for a ride around the bay! Build a sand castle or relax in the sun!LEGO Friends pieces are fully compatible with all LEGO System bricks. Collect all of the LEGO Friends sets for a whole city of LEGO Friends fun!LEGO mini-dolls are figures made especially for the world of LEGO Friends, with thousands of customizable fashion and accessory combinations!Measures over 1&amp;#34; (4cm) tall, 4&amp;#34; (10cm) wide and 4&amp;#34; (12cm) long</description>
  <image-url>http://shopko.com/items/shopko/images/small/59022_0000.jpg</image-url>
  <in-stock></in-stock>
  <isbn></isbn>
  <manufacturer-name></manufacturer-name>
  <manufacturer-sku></manufacturer-sku>
  <name>LEGO Friends Olivias Speedboat</name>
  <price>13.49</price>
  <retail-price>14.99</retail-price>
  <sale-price>13.49</sale-price>
  <sku>59022</sku>
  <upc></upc>
    </product>
  </products>
</cj-api>
```

Comment: I have to run, but it might help others to a) post your code b) any error message and c) your CF version (there are some slight differences)

Comment: Can you pls post a sample of the XML too. Basically post a stand-alone repro case that we can lift out & run ourselves. That said, your problem might just be a missing `.`: `result["cj-api"].products.product`

Comment: Here is the error:You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.
 
The error occurred in E:\inetpub\brickpicker.com\wwwroot\nlms\cfcs\cj.cfc: line 17
15 :  <cfset result = result.Filecontent>
16 :  
17 :  <cfloop index="x" from="1" to="#arrayLen(result["cj-api"].products.product)#">
18 :   <cfset entry = result["cj-api"].products.product[x]>  
19 :   <cfset queryAddRow(results)>

Comment: I don't see how to select one of these comments as the answer?

Comment: @Jeff - Comments cannot be selected. Whoever figured out the issue should post the solution as an "answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[extracted from comments above]

Your problem might just be a missing `.`. Instead of:

```
result["cj-api"]products.product
```

Try:

```
result["cj-api"].products.product
```